# Pojos inside OSGI bundle

Tags: java, osgi, pojo

On an OSGI aplication is it ok to put the application Pojos inside a Bundle and access them through it?
I mean is it a good techique to have a Bundle only for the application pojos?

Comment: What does this even mean?? I can't tell what you're asking, sorry.

Comment: I mean having a Bundle containing all the pojo class declarations, thus the other Bundles in order to use Pojos, would have to make imports from the 'Pojo' Bundle. (Using the Bundle as a pojo library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just think of a scenario your pojo bundle fails getting loaded, because of say any XYZ reason.
doesn't it mean all dependent bundles/functionality will fail??

OSGi is for making things modular and a module as far as my knowledge is concern, is a piece of code which can do one single thing alone or say with least dependency.

Comment: I think it would be appropriate to bundle a domain model (which would be POJO's) that would be used by multiple bundles.  By it's very nature it would be used to exchange information between various other services and the bundles that implement them.  They may be used to define one or more service API's.

Comment: Agree but there can be two type of approaches in one you design such that you end-up writing less code and leave dependencies where in other you write some more code than previous one but remove dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

POJO means "plain old Java object", so you seem to be saying that all the plain Java objects should be in a single bundle. Does that mean all the "non-plain" Java objects should be in other bundles?

This doesn't sound like a good criterion for modularising your application. A module should perform some specific logical function, and so all of the classes in the bundle should be related to performing that function. It doesn't make sense to separate classes into bundles depending on whether they are "plain" or "non-plain", whatever that might mean.

Answer (score 1):

In modularity you want to optimize *cohesion*, which should result in minimal *coupling*. Cohesion means 'related to each other'. A good example of bad cohesion is java.util since people needing a `Collection` are not bound to need a `Runnable` (Util packages or libs are prime examples of horrible cohesion since the only reason they are together in an aggregate because the author in general felt the modules would get too slow).

If you put things together (aggregate) you also aggregate their transitive dependencies. For example, if you use one tiny part of Spring, it generally drags in all of spring. If you're making an application that depends on spring, than that is not a serious problem. Once you you're coupled, it is actually best to use that coupling to the max.

However ...

Building large applications is best done from smaller modules that can be independently designed, tested, and reused between different applications. The trick in designing these reusable modules is to limit their dependencies so that applications are not constrained by those (transitive) dependencies.

So should you put POJO's in a separate bundle? If they are coupled to the application and not reusable, just put them with the application. If you have reusable parts in there, then put those reusable parts in separate modules. The fact that they are a POJO or not is kind of irrelevant, it is the minimal coupling that you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a good idea to have separate bundle for POJOs if they are going to be used extensively by a large number for bundles. It's true that if this bundle fails it will cause other bundles depending on it to fail as well. But this is a desired behaviour since the pojo bundle should not fail in **normal conditions** as it is **NOT** supposed to have business logic as per definition. If it fails that should indicate something terrible wrong, which deserves your attention.

Packaging pojos with application logic in the same bundle also means you would distributing a lot of code where only access to pojo was required.

Comment: @Neil : Not always. POJOs of your applications tend to get used in various modules of your application. Some other POJOs may be used scarcely or just within that bundle. For them there is no need to have a separate bundle. But why not keep the most commonly used application wide POJOs in one bundle just like you would keep your api bundle separate from implementation bundles ? And this applies not just to POJO but all code pieces that are commonly used throughout the application  - Utility classes for example.

Comment: I guess that I simply don't find the term "POJO" to be helpful. Everything should be a POJO, surely?? A much more useful distinction is between API code -- which should be pure interfaces as far as possible -- and implementation code that depends on the APIs. So POJOs are useless as a design artifact abstraction.